# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in

Tags: linux, php, command-line-interface

I know this subject has like ... many duplcates here and there, but trust me I've spent time fetching these posts and my question remains answerless.

I'm running a PHP script on a Debian Linux / Nginx / PHP-FPM / APC / I think that's all.

I'm executing the script from my SSH terminal (CLI) like : `> php plzrunthisFscript.php &`

It used to work flawlessly but now, it returns this famous error.

What I've tried ALREADY and it failed (I mean it didn't change anything) :

- Check what PHP.INI was used with a phpinfo(); inside my script (it's /etc/php5/cli/php.ini)
- maximum_execution time is hardcoded to 0 (means no limit) for CLI if I'm not mistaken.
- Tried to add at begining of my script : `set_time_limit(0)`;
- Tried to add : `ini_set('max_execution_time', -1)`;
- Tried to execute my php command with parameter `-d max_execution_time=0`
- Tried to execute from a web interface (served by Nginx)
- Tried to execute from another web interface (SErver by Apache2 this time) gives same error on page.
- tried to configure `max_execution_time 15` in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` to check if the php.ini that is supposed to be used (because phpinfo() inside my script is ignored or not : **it's ignored**

Everytime, it brings this error, and sometimes even after more than 300 seconds I think, which is really confusing.

If someone has any idea on how to fix this, or has some things I can try, please advise.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you running in safe mode?

Comment: hmmm I don't think so, I'm trying to find a way to check this and tell you back.
OK with the help of a simple script test 
`<?php

// Check for safe mode
if( ini_get(‘safe_mode’) ){
echo “Safe mode is on”;
}else{
echo “Safe mode is off”;
}

?>`

I got : Safe mode is off.

Comment: Have you reduced your script to the PHP equivalent of `sleep 400` to be sure it's not a bug in your script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this ? Do you suggest I write a simple php script with `sleep(400);` inside and then try to execute it from CLI ?

Comment: Yes, that's it - a simple script with no errors in it that takes more than 300 seconds.

Comment: Well, I just did it and it ended correctly. The thing is : Sleep() duration is (according to what I read somewhere) excluded from the timeout count.

Comment: Added 2 more things I tried (Nginx + Apache2)

Comment: Does your script call a function (or include another script) that is perhaps setting the timeout back down to 300?

Comment: It is a Magento script used to rebuild indexes in DB. I used to execute it many times without problems before I changed from Apache2 to Nginx / php-fpm. Or was I just lucky it never took more than 300sec for each request ... Anyway I don't know  the detailed script called by the indexer.php but I can try to search for a patern like maybe ... set_time_limit ?

Comment: I tried to check if php.ini was actually ignored or not aaaaand it's ignored.

Comment: Creating a script with set_time_limit(1) and a loop does end with a max execution time (1) so ... it does respect the set_time_limit function out of my indexer.php script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**God I finaly solved it!**

I think that could be considered as a Magento Bug in a way.
Here is how to reproduce this :

You have Magento (My version is CE 1.7) running with APACHE 2.
One day, you decide to get rid of Apache and try to adopt Nginx.

You configure everything and it's working great, but you end up with this error one day, trying to rebuild your indexes as you often do.

Thing is, when you run (for example) : `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url &`
This script includes another one called abstract.php which contains this awesome function :
`protected function _applyPhpVariables()`

This function will look for a `.htaccess` in your Magento root directory, then parse every single configuration parameters, and will execute the index script with these parameters.

How clever ...

Anyway, to solve this you just need to (delete / rename / burn) this `.htaccess` file, and then everything will go back to normal.

Thanks for your help everyone.